# Expand dictionary keys and convert to int

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in which they keys are strings that describe a list:

```
initial_dict = {'value1':'[1,2,3]',
                'value2':'[4,5,6]'}
```

I wish to switch, expand and convert these as follows:

```
new_dict = {1:1,
            2:1,
            3:1,
            4:2,
            5:2,
            6:2}
```

That is I want to switch the keys and values, then I want each number in the string to become an individual integer key, and on the values side I want the string to also be converted to an int e.g. 'value1'->1.

I am able to switch the keys and values:

```
switched_dict={val:key for (key, val) in initial_dict.items()}
```

And I am able to swap the new values

```
new_values = {"value1":1, "value2":2}
fixed_values = {k: new_values.get(v, v) for k, v in switched_dict.items()}
```

So I now have a dict that looks like this:

```
{'[1,2,3]':1, '[4,5,6]':2}
```

But I am unsure of how to expand and convert the keys to individual ints

Comment: With `fixed_values`, you can achieve the desired result using dictionary comprehension `{i:v for (k,v) in fixed_values.items() for i in ast.literal_eval(k)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the keys to a list of ints:

```
import ast
fixed_values = {'[1,2,3]':1, '[4,5,6]':2}
result = {}
for k, v in fixed_values.items():
  key_ints = ast.literal_eval(k)
  for i in key_ints:
    result[i] = v
```

Comment: If using in python3 use fixed_values.items() rather than fixed_values.iteritems()

Answer (score 1):

Use [ast](https://kite.com/python/docs/ast) module to parse lists.

```
import ast

initial_dict = {'value1':'[1,2,3]',
                'value2':'[4,5,6]'}


expanded_vals = {k: ast.literal_eval(v) for k, v in initial_dict.items()}
result = {}

for k, v in expanded_vals.items():
    for e in v:
        result[e] = k

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string to a list with:

```
import ast
mylist = ast.literal_eval(string)
```

Then just iterate over the list and add the current value to each key in a new dict.

Edit: See @jh314 answer for working code. He was faster.

Comment: What valuable information does this answer added to the above answer?

Comment: @haccks None, but maybe this answer was postet before the others? As you can see, I edited my answer because someone provided a full source code solution.

Answer (score 0):

With a list comprehension using the initial dict:

```
initial_dict = {'value1':'[1,2,3]', 'value2':'[4,5,6]'}
new_values = {"value1": 1, "value2": 2}

{int(n): new_values.get(k) for (k,v) in initial_dict.items() for n in v[1:-1].split(',')}
```

Result:

```
{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an awful one-liner, you can use

```
initial_dict = {'value1':'[1,2,3]', 'value2':'[4,5,6]'}
new_values = {"value1": 1, "value2": 2}

new_dict = {z: y  for x, y in ((v, new_values[k]) for k, v in initial_dict.items()) for z in eval(x)}

# new_dict = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Picking up from the step you said you were unsure of how to proceed and assuming the lists that are stored in your dictionary alway store digits:

1) Iterate each key-value pair

2) Parse each character of the key and update your new dictionary if the character is a digit

```
my_dict = {'[1,2,3]':1,'[4,5,6]':2}
new_dict = {}

for dict_key, dict_value in my_dict.items():
    for character in dict_key[:]:
        if character.isdigit():
            new_dict[character] = dict_value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend your own solution then you can use a dictionary comprehension on `fixed_values`

```
import ast

# ...
new_values = {"value1":1, "value2":2}
fixed_values = {k: new_values.get(v, v) for k, v in switched_dict.items()}

final_dict = {i: v for (k,v) in fixed_values.items() for i in ast.literal_eval(k)}
```